# CakePHP - List of error pages

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Where can I find a  list of the error pages I can customise for Cake 1.3?

e.g. `missing_controller.ctp` and `missing_action.ctp` are a couple I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [ErrorHandler](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/error.php) class and the [error views](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/cake/libs/view/errors) in the core for a complete list.

You can add your own by extending ErrorHandler:

```
// app/app_error.php
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
    function maintenance($params) {
        $this->controller->set(compact('params'));
        $this->controller->flash('Down for maintenance', 'warn');
        $this->_outputMessage('maintenance');
    }
}
```

You can throw errors by calling `Object::cakeError()`:

```
// app/app_controller.php
class AppController extends Controller {
    protected function beforeFilter() {
        if (Configure::read('App.maintenance')) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
            header('Retry-After: ' . HOUR);
            $this->cakeError('maintenance');
        }
    }
}
```

Views go in `app/views/errors/`. :)

Comment: Bear in mind that all this is [changing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions) in CakePHP 2.0